# What are the data types in Prolog?

Tags: types, prolog

According to Wikipedia, the single data type in Prolog [is the term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Data_types). [This](http://users.utcluj.ro/~cameliav/lp/Unification.pdf) text also mentions that "Prolog's single data taype is the term", but then proceeds to explain the "classification of data types in Prolog" (but I thought there was only one type...)
Now, [these slides](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~denzinge/courses/449-winter2004/slides/17-TypesControl-handout.pdf) mention different data types: "numbers, characters and strings".

So, what actually are the data types in Prolog?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24017420/772868) - in particular highlighting the fine point whether or not variables are an extra type.

Answer (score 22):

I'll bite: Prolog has a single data type `term`. Not very useful answer, eh?

Terms are subdivided into

- **Variables.** A placeholder, not unified to any specific term. Variables are identified by symbols matching the regular expression `[A-Z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*`. The variable `_` is special: it is the *anonymous variable*. Every occurrence of `_` denotes a **distinct variable**. For instance, given the fact,

  ```
  foo(1,2,3).
  ```

  A test like `foo(_,_,_).` will succeed whereas a test like `foo(A,A,A).` will fail.

  Once a variable is unified with (bound to) a value, however, it ceases to be variable: unless undone by backtracking it is forever and always what it unified with.
- **Numbers** are either `float` or `integer`. Usual sorts of rules apply (e.g. `-321` is an integer, `-321.0` or something like `-3.21e+02` is a float.
- **Atoms** are *names*, usually denoted by by a word beginning with a lower-case letter (e.g. `atom`), matching the regular rexpression `[a-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*`. Alternatively, atoms may be delimited by apostrophes (e.g., `'atom'`), which conveniently allow the use of characters not otherwise allowable. The syntax for atom is somewhat more complex than that: essentially anything that doesn't fall into another category will form an atom (e.g., the special atom `[]` denoting the empty list and the comma (`,`) denoting conjunction are all atoms.
- Everything else is essentially a **structure** i.e. tuples of terms, tagged by a *functor* (a name matching the rules for an atom) with an *arity* (number of arguments). One can even treat atoms as structure of arity 0.

There is syntactic sugar poured on top of prolog's other "data types":

- **Lists** are denoted by the structure `./2`, with the left-hand argument being the head of the list and the right-hand its tail. The empty list being denoted by the atom `[]`. For instance,

  - the list `[a]` is internally represented as `.(a,[])`,
  - the list `[a,b]` as `.(a,.(b,[]))` and
  - the list `[a,b|[c]]` as `.(a,.(b,.(c,[])))`.

  One should note that one can write a list using either notation: they will unify appropriately. You can see the attraction of using the bracketed list notation, however.
- Similar syntactic sugar is applied to **strings**. A string can be written as a string of text delimited by double-quotes: `"The cat and the hat"`. Internally however, strings are represented as **lists** of integers representing the code points for each of the characters in the implementations internal encoding. For instance, the string `"cat"` is internally represented (in ASCII/UTF-8) as the list `[99,97,116]`. `"cat"` is easier to read, eh?

Comment: I understand. But it sounds strange that it's a "single" data type which actually "is subdivided into" others... Anyway, if this is the way it's described, I accept it -- but I'd like to know what criteria is used to tell when two data types are distinct. (From your description I have to accept that numbers, atoms and lists are of the same type).

Comment: @josh: numbers are different than atoms - You can't do arithmetic on atoms. The reason for the "single data type" is that prolog is defined in terms `B^)` of itself. But I can see where you're coming from. You could collapse prolog down to having just vars and nonvars, where nonvars are numbers or structures, if you look at an atom as a structure of arity 0.

Comment: "structures" are rather called compound terms, there is even a built-in `compound/1` to test for them.

Answer (score 4):

In my (not so humble) opinion, saying that "[The data objects of the language are called terms. A term is either a constant, a variable, or a compound term](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dsyn_002dtrm_002dove.html#ref_002dsyn_002dtrm_002dove)" (and a clause is a compound term) sounds good, but the [EBNF syntax](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dsyn_002dsyn.html#ref_002dsyn_002dsyn) actually has about *6 whole pages*, so there is (a lot of) hidden structure not expressed in that statement. So a program text can be decomposed into these few syntactic classes, but one is also interested in Lists, Dicts, Strings etc. which must assembled from these low-level pieces in particular ways. Anyway, a graphic follows, it applies in particular to SWI-Prolog but "Other Prologs" are mostly similar -- unless they are "Really Other Prolog" (for example the Answer Set Programming Prologs may be simpler, I really don't know).

Here is an SVG diagram ([source here](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/tree/master/swipl_notes/about_swipl_data_types/swipl_data_type_tree)):

[image: Types of SWI-Prolog]

The above is somewhat specific to SWI-Prolog because:

- There is a `dict` (associative array) data type.
- `string` is a separate data type in SWI Prolog. Traditionally, the 'string' is just a 'list of characters'.
- The empty list is a specific atom `[]`. Traditionally, the empty list is similar to a null pointer.
- The listbox/consbox functor is `[|]` instead of the traditional `.`.
- There are compound terms of arity 0, like `a()`. Traditionally, these don't exist.
- Rational numbers `NrD` exist.

For for those who like history, here is the description of "term" from the first Prolog Manual, written by Philippe Roussel in September 1975, which can be found at [Prolog Héritage](http://prolog-heritage.org/en/ph12.html).

[image: First writeup of Prolog term]

Answer (score 3):

> the single data type in Prolog is the term

This statement is both correct and somewhat useless at the same time. It goes to say that types do not play much role in Prolog: everything is a term, variables are untyped, they will unify with other terms as required.

Numbers, atoms, and compound terms, on the other hand, are not data types - they are different kinds of of terms, which is slightly different. Compound terms further subdivide into lists, strings, and "other" kinds of functor-like terms.

Answer (score 2):

The ISO standard and its corrigendum 2 features a couple
of test predicates that test the data-types in Prolog.
Richard O'Keefe used to arrange these test predicates
http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/okeefe.txt
as follows:

```
                    true
                      |
            +---------+---------+
            |                   |
         nonvar                var
            |
  +---------+--------------------------+
  |                                    |
compound                           atomic=constant
                                       |
            +----------------+---------+---------+
            |                |                   |
          number          string             atom=symbol
            |
    +-------+-------+ 
    |               |
 integer            float
```

I have left out rational and complex which are not part of ISO Prolog, but I have kept string although it is also not part of ISO Prolog, but for example genuine strings, i.e. not the double quoted shorthand for character code lists but a real datatype, are currently found in SWI-Prolog version 7.  Generally ISO Prolog allows adding new data types to a Prolog implementation.

The tree has some nice properties:

**1) Siblings are exclusive:**
If s1, .., sn are siblings, then maximum one of the
test predicates si will hold for a given argument. So for example we know that either float(X) or integer(X) or none of the two holds, but not both together can hold for a particular X.

**2) Children are contained in their parent:**
If c is a child and p is parent, then c implies p. So for example we know that if number(X) holds, then also atomic(X) holds for a particular X.

There are more datatypes already defined in the ISO core standard that cannot so easily be fit into the tree. For example an atom of length 1 is called character. An integer between 0..max_code is called a character code. An integer between 0..255 is called a byte. Sometimes a character code or byte resp. character might also include -1 resp. end_of_file. These datatypes don't have their own test predicate, tests have to be derived from other predicates.

Strictly speaking the ISO core standard also defines list cells simply as compounds of arity 2 with functor '.', and the empty list as the atom '[]'. Some Prolog systems, like for example SWI-Prolog version 7 violate this rule and use another functor for list cells. The newer ISO test predicate callable/1 joins atoms and compounds.

Then there are more holistic test predicates which don't look only at the manifest type of the root element of the given term. For example the predicate ground/1 has to look at the whole term, so does the test predicate acyclic_term/1, both being part of the ISO standard.

Answer (score -1):

See http://ktiml.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/data_struct.html

Term is a container that can contain several different kinds of data (think inheritance in object oriented languages)