# Which meanings of "type" are used in the standard?

Tags: iso-prolog

In part one of the ISO standard for Prolog, ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995, the notion of "type" is used to refer to different things. This often leads to confusion.
For example, a page called IsoErrata ([archived version](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/ECLiPSeWiki_Prolog_IsoErrata-2014-01-22), [source](http://eclipseclp.org/wiki/Prolog/IsoErrata)) states (note that this page is not related to ISO):

> 7.12.2 and 8.1.2.1
>
> There is a confusion about what a "type" is. There seem to be 3
>   different groups:
>
> - Those that are listed in 8.1.2.1 and also occur as ValidTypes in type_error terms in 7.12.2.b
> - Those that are listed in 8.1.2.1 and occur as ValidDomain in domain_error terms in 7.12.2.c
> - Those that are listed in 8.1.2.1 only
>
> In addition, there are ValidDomains in 7.12.2.c that are not listed in
>   8.1.2.1, presumably by mistake (eg. io_mode).
>
> 8.14.3.3.f
>
> The template requires the type `atom_or_atom_list` for the 3rd argument, but strangely the required error term here is
>   `type_error(list,Operator)`. This results in (see examples)
>
> `op(30,xfy,0)  =====>  error(type_error(list,0))`
>
> where `type_error(atom,0)` or `type_error(atom_or_atom_list,0)` would be more appropriate (but note that `atom_or_atom_list` is not among the
>   ValidTypes listed in 7.12.2!). For ECLiPSe we have therefore opted for
>   `type_error(list,Op)` only if `Op` is an improper list, and
>   `type_error(atom,Op)` if `Op` is any other non-atom.

So in which meanings is "type" used, and what to do about above confusion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are essentially three different uses for "type" in ISO/IEC 13211-1:

1. Types as defined in 7.1 Types. These are: variable (7.1.1), integer (7.1.2), floating point (7.1.3), atom (7.1.4), compound term (7.1.5) and some types based on them. The next two uses will often refer to 7.1 or to terminology (3 Definitions) for its definition. What is important is that here, variables are included. This classification is motivated by Prolog's syntax:

   > **7.1 Types**
   >
   > The type of any term is determined by its abstract syntax (6.1.2).
2. Types as defined in 7.12.2 b. These are the types that are used in type errors which are of the form `type_error(ValidType, Culprit)`. Note that variables are now no longer included since these are either signaled as instantiation errors (7.12.2 a) or uninstantiation errors ([7.12.2 k, Cor.2](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#C1)).

> `ValidType` ∈ { `atom, atomic, byte, callable, character, compound, evaluable, float, in_byte, in_character, integer, list, number, pair, predicate_indicator` }

3. Types as used in the Template and modes subclause:

   > **8.1.2.1 Type of an argument**

   > The type of each argument is defined by one of the following atoms:
   > `atom, atom_or_atom_list, atomic, byte, callable_term, character, character_code, character_code_list, character_list, clause, close_options_list, compound_term, evaluable, flag, head, in_byte, in_character, in_character_code, integer, io_mode, list, nonvar, number, operator_specifier, predicate_indicator, read_options_list, source_sink, stream, stream_options_list, stream_or_alias, stream_position, stream_property, term, write_options_list`

Above quote mentioned only 7.12.2 and 8.1.2.1 and how they relate to each other. So this needs some more elaboration:

Types of 7.12.2 are reported with type errors.  But types in 8.1.2.1 only serve in the Template and modes subclause of  the [definition of a built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302735/what-are-the-best-prolog-programming-practices-and-style-guidelines/23312956#23312956). They are not per se suited to be used for errors. In a concrete [definition of a built-in predicate](/a/23312956/772868), there is a subclause **x.y.z.2 Template and modes** and **x.y.z.3 Errors**.  Here are some examples of types of 8.1.2.1 (bold in the list above).

### `write_options_list`

There is no direct one-to-one correspondence between `write_options_list` and the concrete types used in the errors. Instead, a type `list` and a domain `write_option` is used. So the complex type `write_options_list` is never signaled:

> **8.14.2.2 Template and modes**
>
> `write_term(@stream_or_alias, @term, @write_options_list)`
>
> **8.14.2.3 Errors**
>
> ...
>
> c) `Options` is neither a partial list nor a list
> — `type_error(list, Options).`
>
> ...
>
> e) An element `E` of the `Options` list is neither a
> variable nor a valid write-option
> — `domain_error(write_option, E).`

### `atom_or_atom_list`

This is even more complex. On the one hand an atom list is expected, but also an atom is fine. So we have `list` and `atom` as relevant types:

> **8.14.3.2 Template and modes**
>
> `op(+integer, +operator_specifier, @atom_or_atom_list)`
>
> **8.14.3.3 Errors**
>
> ...
>
> f) `Operator` is neither a partial list nor a list nor
> an
> atom
> — `type_error(list, Operator).`
>
> g) An element `E` of the `Operator` list is neither a
> variable nor
> an atom
> — `type_error(atom, E).`

It is equally plausible to produce `atom` for error f. On the other hand, both errors are equally applicable, and `list` is definitely the best for malformed lists like `[a|nonlist]`, whereas `atom` is not necessarily better for `111` which might be an OCR error of `[l]`.

### `callable_term`

The corresponding type error contains `callable`. Like in

> **8.10.1.2 Template and modes**
>
> `findall(?term, +callable_term, ?list)`
>
> **8.10.1.3 Errors**
>
> ...
>
> b) Goal is neither a variable nor a callable term
> — `type_error(callable, Goal)`.

### `in_character_code`

There is neither a corresponding type in 7.12.2 b, nor a domain in 7.12.2 c. But in 7.12.2 f it is defined for representation errors:

> **8.12.1.2 Template and modes**
>
> ...
> `get_code(?in_character_code)`
> `get_code(@stream_or_alias, ?in_character_code)`
>
> **8.12.1.3 Errors**
>
> ...
>
> j) `Code` is an integer but not an in-character code
>    (7.1.2.2)
> — `representation_error(in_character_code).`

### `io_mode`

This **is** listed in 8.1.2.1, contrary to the quoted text. It also appears in 7.12.2 c and is used:

> **8.11.5.3 Errors**
>
> ...
>
> h) `Mode` is an atom but not an input/output mode
>  —
> `domain_error(io_mode, Mode).`

### `character_code_list`

Similar to `write_options_list`. However, it is erroneously mentioned in 7.12.2 c. That's an error in the standard which has been removed in [Cor.3:2017](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/WDCor3#C8).